# Add module to aar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Hi guys I am facing a problem while updating my libraries to android studio(0.8.+) library strucutre.
I am trying to build some aar files. Just to clarify, this is how I#ve done it

I do have a base library in the app module
Besides this library there is another module from a advertiser "advertiser"

In the buil.gradle  file of the app I do have this line in my depencies:
`compile project(':advertiser')`

What I want is that the second module from the advertiser is included in the *.aar file but it isn't
`gradlew aR`

How do I link them the static way so the second module is build within the aar file?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each Android module creates a separate .aar file during the build. If you want both of them to be in the same module, you'll need to merge the sources together into one module.

Comment: thanks for the answer, just found the doc http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format

Comment: Is there a way to merge them by gradle or do i have to do it manually

Comment: I think you have to merge the source modules together. Trying to merge two .aars will be tricky because you'll have to merge the manifest files together.

Comment: so if there will be a update of the advertiser's project i'll have to copy the files

Comment: Yes, but it's not clear why you want to include the advertiser library's files in your .aar in the first place. It's okay for it to be separate, and it's probably better because it will avoid potential future build problems if someone else tries to use your .aar.

Comment: Scott that's the point, i'll build several aar files and upload them to my maven, so if the advertiser will update it, i'll just have to update my repo version, the depency will be in the build gradle of my library which should be included in the aar, isn't it?